# collection not saving model if passed as property of model

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to create a Backbone application without using a global collections variable. this is what I mean. Initially, I created a model and added it to a collection like this in a function in my view

```
   this.mymodel = new MyModel();
   this.mymodel.addToCollection();
```

Inside the `addToCollection()` function (called on the instance of the model), I added the instance of the model (represented by `this`) and then called save on it

```
addToCollection(){
  mycollectionglobalvariable.add(this) //this global collection variable was created on application init
  this.save();
}
```

In the collection, I have it set up to save to localStorage and everything works fine, except that I didn't want to use a global variable for the collection (primarily to make testing easier), so in my main view I pass the collection with the collection property (this implies that I passed the collection to the main view and set it as the this.mycollection property)

```
    this.mymodel = new MyModel(collection: this.mycollection);
```

Now, in the constructor to that model, I set the collection property

```
   constructor(options){
      this.collection = options.collection;
   }
```

and  the addToCollection method is now like this

```
 addToCollection(){
   this.collection.add(this);
   this.save();
 }
```

The result is that the model is getting added to the collection but it is not getting saved.  Why doesn't the model get saved when I pass the collection as property of the model?

You can see [here in the Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) that it supports passing the collection as a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you are simply overwriting the constructor. You should probably call through to the default constructor too: `Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);`.

However take a look at the source code for the model's constructor: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-53. It adds the collection option to the model already, so you can remove your constructor entirely.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
  var attrs = attributes || {};
  options || (options = {});
  this.cid = _.uniqueId(this.cidPrefix);
  this.attributes = {};
  if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
  if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
  attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));
  this.set(attrs, options);
  this.changed = {};
  this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Finally, it may have just been a typo, but you should pass the options hash to your model as the second parameter.

```
this.mymodel = new MyModel({}, {collection: this.mycollection});
```

Check out this jsfiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mfze3abg/

Comment: Thank you very much.  I did it the way you suggested at the end of your answer, but I'm wondering if you can complete your answer by showing exactly how/where etc to call through the default constructor `Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);.`  Do I call that from inside the model? from the view?

Comment: What I was getting at is: you don't need to overwrite the constructor. Check out the jsfiddle above for a more complete example.

(But *if* you wanted to overwrite the constructor, which I don't recommend in this case, you would call `Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments)` from the constructor.)